# How to vectorize a function which contains an if statement?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Let's say we have the following function:

```
def f(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return 0
    return x/y
```

This works fine with scalar values. Unfortunately when I try to use numpy arrays for `x` and `y` the comparison `y == 0` is treated as an array operation which results in an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-9884e2c3d1cd> in <module>()
----> 1 f(np.arange(1,10), np.arange(10,20))

<ipython-input-10-fbd24f17ea07> in f(x, y)
      1 def f(x, y):
----> 2     if y == 0:
      3         return 0
      4     return x/y

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

<strike>I tried to use `np.vectorize` but it doesn't make a difference, the code still fails with the same error.</strike> `np.vectorize` is one option which gives the result I expect.

The only solution that I can think of is to use `np.where` on the `y` array with something like:

```
def f(x, y):
    np.where(y == 0, 0, x/y)
```

which doesn't work for scalars.

Is there a better way to write a function which contains an if statement? It should work with both scalars and arrays.

Comment: Are you saying you want to pass a numpy array for `y` but just a single number for `x`?  Or vice versa, or both?

Comment: If you wrap your y and x in `np.asarray`, the `where` version will work. But note that `x/y` is evaluated everywhere, and so you may get a warning or exception (depending on your floating-point flags) if any of `y==0`.

Comment: @BrenBarn both `x` and `y` are arrays in the second case. Edited my answer to make that more explicit.

Comment: `np.vectorize` works fine here `:)`

Comment: @moarningsun Can you post an answer with the code?

Answer (score 21):

One way is to convert `x` and `y` to numpy arrays inside your function:

```
def f(x, y):
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    return np.where(y == 0, 0, x/y)
```

This will work when one of `x` or `y` is a scalar and the other is a numpy array.  It will also work if they are both arrays that can be broadcast.  It won't work if they're arrays of incompatible shapes (e.g., 1D arrays of different lengths), but it's not clear what the desired behavior would be in that case anyway.

Comment: Change `np.array(x)` to `np.asarray(x)` (likewise for `y`) and you've got it.

Comment: Add `with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):` before the return (and indent the return), to silence the warnings.

Answer (score 8):

I wonder what the problem is you're facing with `np.vectorize`. It works fine on my system:

```
In [145]: def f(x, y):
     ...:     if y == 0:
     ...:         return 0
     ...:     return x/y

In [146]: vf = np.vectorize(f)

In [147]: vf([[3],[10]], [0,1,2,0])
Out[147]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  1,  0],
       [ 0, 10,  5,  0]])
```

Note that the result `dtype` is determined by the result of the first element. You can also set the desired output yourself:

```
In [148]: vf = np.vectorize(f, otypes=[np.float])

In [149]: vf([[3],[10]], [0,1,2,0])
Out[149]: 
array([[  0. ,   3. ,   1.5,   0. ],
       [  0. ,  10. ,   5. ,   0. ]])
```

There are more examples in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

Comment: `otypes=[np.float]` was the piece that I was missing.

Comment: np.vectorize is not provided for performance, it is basically a for loop as stated in the docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Answer (score 7):

You can use a masked array that will perform the division only where `y!=0`:

```
def f(x, y):
    x = np.atleast_1d(np.array(x))
    y = np.atleast_1d(np.ma.array(y, mask=(y==0)))
    ans = x/y
    ans[ans.mask]=0
    return np.asarray(ans)
```

Comment: Assuming you meant the last line to return `x/y`, this sets all values where `y==0` to `1`.

Comment: @PokeyMcPokerson thank you for the comment... Iwrote it in a hurry later on and now I've fixed it

Comment: If you mask the `x` array instead of the `y`, i.e. `x = np.ma.array(x, mask=(y==0))` and `y = np.array(y)`, it runs at about double the speed. It also gets rid of the warnings.

Answer (score 6):

A kind of clunky but effective way is to basically pre-process the data:

```
def f(x, y):
    if type(x) == int and type(y) == int: return x/y # Will it ever be used for this?

    # Change scalars to arrays
    if type(x) == int: x = np.full(y.shape, x, dtype=y.dtype)
    if type(y) == int: y = np.full(x.shape, y, dtype=x.dtype)

    # Change all divide by zero operations to 0/1
    div_zero_idx = (y==0)
    x[div_zero_idx] = 0
    y[div_zero_idx] = 1

    return x/y
```

I timed all the different approaches:

```
def f_mask(x, y):
    x = np.ma.array(x, mask=(y==0))
    y = np.array(y)
    ans = x/y
    ans[ans.mask]=0
    return np.asarray(ans)

def f_where(x, y):
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    return np.where(y == 0, 0, x/y)

def f_vect(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return 0
    return x/y

vf = np.vectorize(f_vect)

print timeit.timeit('f(np.random.randint(10, size=array_length), np.random.randint(10, size=array_length))', number=10000, setup="from __main__ import f; import numpy as np; array_length=1000")
print timeit.timeit('f_mask(np.random.randint(10, size=array_length), np.random.randint(10, size=array_length))', number=10000, setup="from __main__ import f_mask; import numpy as np; array_length=1000")
print timeit.timeit('f_where(np.random.randint(10, size=array_length), np.random.randint(10, size=array_length))', number=10000, setup="from __main__ import f_where; import numpy as np; array_length=1000")
print timeit.timeit('vf(np.random.randint(10, size=array_length), np.random.randint(10, size=array_length))', number=10000, setup="from __main__ import vf; import numpy as np; array_length=(1000)")

# f
# 0.760189056396

# f_mask
# 2.24414896965

# f_where
# RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide return np.where(y == 0, 0, x/y)
# 1.08176398277

# f_vect
# 3.45374488831
```

The first function is the quickest, and has no warnings. The time ratios are similar if x or y are scalars. For higher dimensional arrays, the masked array approach gets relatively faster (it's still the slowest though).

Answer (score 0):

one methode is to use the numpy.heavside() function. so, in lieu of writing your function interms of if statmennt use the heaviside function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use heaviside function np.heaviside in lieu of if statement
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEZON.png)

Answer (score -1):

Consider that you have a predicted vector / np array :
[0,1,0,1,1,0] and you want to convert it to the sequence ['N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N']

```
import numpy as np

y_pred = np.array([0,1,0,1,1,0])

def toYN(x):
    if x > 0:
        return "Y"
    else:
        return "N"

vf_YN = np.vectorize(toYN)
Loan_Status = vf_YN(y_pred)
```

Loan_Status will contain ['N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N']