# Inexplicable "divide by zero" RuntimeWarning with numpy masked arrays

Tags: python, numpy, divide-by-zero

I am encountering a divide by zero Runtime Warning in Numpy, and I cannot understand why.

I am talking the inverse (elementwise) of a masked array, and none of the valid values of the array are close to 0.

In the following formula: exct and rpol are scalars, and geocentp is a masked array (so temp and Rearth are going to be masked array too).

```
temp = sqrt(1. - exct ** 2. * cos(geocentp)**2.)
print temp.count()
print temp.min(), temp.max()

Rearth = rpol / temp
print Rearth.count()
print Rearth.min(), Rearth.max()
```

The print output is:

```
5680418
0.996616 0.999921
5680418
6357.09 6378.17
```

And still, I get the Warning:

```
seviri_lst_toolbox.py:1174: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  Rearth = rpol / temp
```

This is weird, right? The usual behaviour of a masked array is that masked values are not divided. If a division by zero on a valid value occurs, the value is masked, which is not the case as the 'count()' gives the exact number of valid values before and after the division...

I'm lost... Anybody has an idea?

---

EDIT:
Following the answer of RomanGotsiy, I could get rid of the warning by changing the float numerator for a masked array:

```
Rearth = rpol * np.ma.ones(geocentp.shape, dtype=np.float32) / temp
```

But this is clearly not ideal. This matrix (temporarily) created overloads my memory. Is there another way to get around that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vectorize a function which contains an if statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646472/how-to-vectorize-a-function-which-contains-an-if-statement)

Comment: This is a known problem: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4959

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that warning is shown because of `rpol` type is not masked array.

Look through my console output:

```
>>> import numpy as np, numpy.ma as ma
>>>
>>> x = ma.array([1., -1., 3., 4., 5., 6.])
>>> y = ma.array([1., 2., 0., 4., 5., 6.])
>>> print x/y
[1.0 -0.5 -- 1.0 1.0 1.0]
>>> # assign to "a" general numpy array
>>> a = np.array([1., -1., 3., 4., 5., 6.])
>>> print a/y
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
[1.0 -0.5 -- 1.0 1.0 1.0]
>>>
```

Comment: That seems to be the problem indeed. rpol is a float. How could I go around that (stupid) problem?