# Vectorize a function with a condition

Tags: numpy, conditional-statements, vectorization

I would like to vectorize a function with a condition, meaning to calculate its values with array arithmetic. `np.vectorize` handles vectorization, but it does not work with array arithmetic, so it is not a complete solution

An answer was given as the solution in the question "[How to vectorize a function which contains an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646472/how-to-vectorize-a-function-which-contains-an-if-statement)" but did not prevent errors here; see the MWE below.

```
import numpy as np

def myfx(x):
    return np.where(x < 1.1, 1, np.arcsin(1 / x))

y = myfx(x)
```

This runs but raises the following warnings:

```
<stdin>:2: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
<stdin>:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arcsin
```

What is the problem, or is there a better way to do this?

I think this could be done by

1. Getting the indices `ks` of `x` for which `x[k] > 1.1` for each `k` in `ks`.
2. Applying `np.arcsin(1 / x[ks])` to the slice `x[ks]`, and using 1 for the rest of the elements.
3. Recombining the arrays.

I am not sure about the efficiency, though.

Comment: Related, but not quite a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52622172/2988730

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `np.where(x < 1.1, 1, np.arcsin(1 / x))` is equivalent to

```
mask = x < 1.1
a = 1
b = np.arcsin(1 / x)
np.where(mask, a, b)
```

Notice that you're calling `np.arcsin` on all the elements of `x`, regardless of whether `1 / x <= 1` or not. Your basic plan is correct. You can do the operations in-place on an output array using the `where` keyword of [`np.arcsin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arcsin.html) and [`np.reciprocal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reciprocal.html), without having to recombine anything:

```
def myfx(x):
    mask = (x >= 1.1)
    out = np.ones(x.shape)
    np.reciprocal(x, where=mask, out=out) # >= 1.1 implies != 0
    return np.arcsin(out, where=mask, out=out)
```

Using [`np.ones`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) ensures that the unmasked elements of `out` are initialized correctly. An equivalent method would be

```
out = np.empty(x.shape)
out[~mask] = 1
```

Comment: But no function exists to do this automatically? It seems like the sort of thing that should have a convenience function.

Comment: @BGreen. I sort of see your point, but keep in mind that there's more than one way to handle this. I suggest adding a utility to your project.

Comment: That's fair. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can always find an arithmetic expression that prevents the "divide by zero".

Example:

```
def myfx(x):
    return np.where( x < 1.1, 1, np.arcsin(1/np.maximum(x, 1.1)) )
```

The values where `x<1.1` in the right wing are not used, so it's not an issue computing `np.arcsin(1/1.1)` where `x < 1.1`.

Comment: This does not solve the issue of passing values > 1 to arcsin

Comment: When vectorizing code in C, it is common to compute both expressions, and use a mask at the end. Something like `y = (a & msk) | (b & (~msk))`. It used for avoiding `if` statements and improving performance. (It is commonly used in SIMD optimized code). It reduces the code readability but more efficient in many cases.

Comment: Sure, but this is a fundamentally different situation and I think you're ignoring the cause of the second warning.

Comment: You are right about the second warning. I modified the expression to `1/np.maximum(x, 1.1)`. It think it could be a useful trick.

Comment: But does it actually result in the same thing? Now, instead of replacing values with 1, you are setting them to `arcsin(1 / 1.1)`

Comment: Really? The expression is `np.where( x < 1.1, 1, ...`

Comment: Numpy does not do lazy evaluation. Function calls are done in sequence. Take a look at my answer. It's the first thing I address.